# Dynamically Add Content in Google Drive Document File

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

[image]I have create dynamical file and after I have to add some dynamic content from fckeditor put on that file on save button how to add content or text. Add on google document file using java script code of google drive API in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function gd_updateFile()
                {
                    var my_text = "your content";

                    var folderId  =  "fileid";
                    var fileId = "your folder id ";


                    const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
                    const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
                    const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

                    var contentType = "text/html";
                    var metadata = {'mimeType': contentType,};

                    var multipartRequestBody =
                        delimiter +  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
                        JSON.stringify(metadata) +
                        delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +
                        my_text +
                        close_delim;


                    var request  = gapi.client.request({
                        'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/'+folderId+"?fileId="+fileId+"&uploadType=multipart",
                        'method': 'PUT',
                        'params': {'fileId': fileId, 'uploadType': 'multipart'},
                        'headers': {'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'},
                        'body': multipartRequestBody,
                        callback:callback,
                 });



                    $(".update_file_out_put").html(callback);

                 if (!callback) 
                     { 
                      callback = function(file) 
                      { 
                             //console.log(file);
                      }; 
                     }
                }
```